# Deserialize JSON objects one by one using json.net (XAMARIN)

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to this. I'm using Xamarin in VS2017.

I have a JSON file as follows

```
[ {  
  "LEDGERID":1,
  "LEDGERNAME":"CASH",
  "UNDER":"19",
  "CREDIT_PERIOD":"0",
  "CREDIT_LIMIT":"0",
  "LEDGER_TYPE":"DEBIT",
  "OPENBAL":120196.00,
  "STATUS":"True",
  "USER_GEN":false,
  "date":null,
  "arabic_name":null},
  {
  "LEDGERID":2,
  "LEDGERNAME":"PURCHASE",
  "UNDER":"17",
  "CREDIT_PERIOD":"0",
  "CREDIT_LIMIT":"0",
  "LEDGER_TYPE":"DEBIT",
  "OPENBAL":0.00,
  "STATUS":"True",
  "USER_GEN":false,
  "date":null,
  "arabic_name":null
  }
  ]
```

This is a lengthier one but i made it short for easy understanding. I need to take it one by one because sometimes I need to give test cases before taking the values to the list. I am using PCL storage in XAMARIN tostore the Json File. I went througn the documents of NewtonSoft Json deserializing. I hope some one can help me thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to give test cases"? You can always deserialize to a list, then modify the instances and the list afterwards. It'll be easier to help you if we understand more of your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your json isn't valid, you had the word `nul`, however i'm sure it was a mistake
2. Take your json to http://json2csharp.com/ and create a class from it and call it what ever you want
3. Get your self the Json.net Nuget package

**Example class**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int LEDGERID { get; set; }
    public string LEDGERNAME { get; set; }
    public string UNDER { get; set; }
    public string CREDIT_PERIOD { get; set; }
    public string CREDIT_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string LEDGER_TYPE { get; set; }
    public double OPENBAL { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public bool USER_GEN { get; set; }
    public object date { get; set; }
    public object arabic_name { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Comment: nul was a mistake. I already got my Json.net nuget package. What should i do if want to add those ledger ids to a list and print in a label

Comment: @mohammedmazin updated... it will give you back a list

Comment: I'm new to this. Suppose i have two labels LABEL1 and Label2. How could I print Ledger id 1 and  Ledger id 2 to them respectively?

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend using idiomatic C# names (LedgerId, LedgerName etc) and using the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to control serialization, rather than have JSON dictate the names used in C# code.

Comment: @mohammedmazin: That sounds like it's not really about the topic of this question, but about Xamarin binding. I suggest you research that separately and ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: Here we obtain a list for the both objects right? What if I need to take the objects one by one?

Comment: @mohammedmazin `foreach(var result in results) { // you now have access to each result }`

Comment: @mohammedmazin take all of DaisyShipton's recommendations, you now know how to Deserialize, if you need more help with lists and or bindings you are best to start another question